# Reuse the same query but just update the value of the nested variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design

In T-SQL, if I wanted to reuse the same query but just update the value of the nested variable, how can I accomplish this? I have tried both examples below, however, instead of yielding an ID, both return a *null* value.

I am currently writing a script to populate a significantly reduced-sized database, that contains all of the same tables that the original database had, and is entirely composed of mock data for testing purposes. With that being said, I need to grab IDs from various type tables, as well as, various other data from other tables that need to be linked to one another. In order to do this, it would be great if I could reuse the same query by passing new values into the nested variable(s).

Ideally, I would love to write a function where I can call that function and just pass in different values for the parameters. Is there any way that I can do this?

NOTE: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

**First:**

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(20);
DECLARE @queryTable int = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Table WHERE [Name]=@var1);

SET @var1 = 'CellPhone';
SELECT @queryTable;

SET @var1 = 'HomePhone';
SELECT @queryTable;
```

**Second:**

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(20);
DECLARE @queryTable int = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Table WHERE [Name]=@var1);

SET @var1 = 'CellPhone';
DECLARE @queryTable_CellPhone INT = (SELECT (@queryTable));

SET @var1 = 'HomePhone';
DECLARE @queryTable_HomePhone INT = (SELECT (@queryTable));

SELECT @queryTable_CellPhone;
SELECT @queryTable_HomePhone;
```

Comment: You can't use variables for object names. But you can compose a query using variables for object names as `nvarchar(max)` and then use [`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Make sure to properly quote the object names. [`quotename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `sp_executesql` and output variable:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)= 
   N'SELECT @query_table = ID FROM dbo.Table WHERE [Name]=@var1';
DECLARE @query_table INT, @va1 VARCHAR(100);

SET @var1 = 'CellPhone';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@query_table INT OUTPUT, @var1 VARCHAR(100)',
     @query_table OUT, @var1;
SELECT @query_table;

SET @var1 = 'HomePhone';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@query_table INT OUTPUT, @var1 VARCHAR(100)',
     @query_table OUT, @var1;
SELECT @query_table;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=84455055bb55b10ea5cdcb6c9098765f)**

---

And without intercepting result:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)= N'SELECT ID FROM dbo.Tab WHERE [Name]=@var1';
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(100);

SET @var1 = 'CellPhone';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@var1 VARCHAR(100)', @var1;

SET @var1 = 'HomePhone';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@var1 VARCHAR(100)', @var1;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b42171c63e1900b386ac532686317315)**